# Namespace error when importing XML-file into InDesign

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

The task is to import an XML-file into InDesign CS6 while processing that file with an XSL transformation. In order to apply paragraph-styles to the imported text, the attribute "aid:pstyle" is added via XSLT. A very brief example:

XML file to be imported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <Paragraph>This is my first XML-Import.</Paragraph>
</Root>
```

XSL transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Paragraph">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
               <xsl:value-of select="'myParagraphStyle'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running the XSLT externally on the input file, we get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Paragraph xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" aid:pstyle="myParagraphStyle">This is my first XML-Import.</Paragraph>
</Root>
```

which can be imported into InDesign with the desired results.
However, when we import the primary input and apply the XSLT *during* that import, InDesign complains about wrong namespaces. The error message is "DOM-Transformationsfehler: Ungültiges Namespace" (we have a German InDesign version, in English it should be somewhat like "DOM-Transformation error: illegal namespace.")

Any clue how to get my XML imported while applying the XSLT on that import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I thought you were using the wrong namespace IRI for xmlns:aid, but revisiting other examples I found both "http://ns.adobe.com/Adobe InDesign/4.0/" with an additional blank and  "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" used. Actually the latter appears to be the correct one as the plugin SDK has a matching definition.

Then a stylesheet version="2.0" appeared a bit daring, I changed that to "1.0" but it still did not import.

FinallyI  got it: InDesign is *very* picky about namespaces. Apparently the namespace must be introduced at the root element. The following version works with my InDesign CS6:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <Root xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Paragraph">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="aid:pstyle">
                <xsl:value-of select="'myParagraphStyle'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your valuable help - your solution is very right